# Looking to sort tables in a database based on the last time table was updated

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm looking to sort multiple tables that are in a database based on the last time the table was updated. The tables all have a column called `Update_Time` that updates the timestamp when that row is updated in the table. I have tried with the `UPDATE_TIME` from the TABLE_SCHEMA, but that updates when any of the tables on my webpage gets updated. Below is what I have tried that doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase' 
ORDER BY (
    SELECT MAX(`Update_Time`) AS "Last Updated" FROM `myTable`
);
```

Answer (score 2):

First, your `order by` clause is using a date, not a column, to perform the sort, so every row is sorted with the same value which has no effect. For example, if the most recent update date is `2024-01-06` your query becomes:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase' 
ORDER BY '2024-01-06';
```

Second, the schema information held by the database server is not *the data* it's meta data about the tables. You would have to use some dynamic SQL to get the list of tables from the schema info then run queries to get the most recent update in each table, then rank the tables by that date.

What do you actully need the most recent update for? There might be an easier way to do this if you tell us more about the problem you are actully trying to solve.

In response to your comment about getting this working with the table design you have, you can use a `union` query if the number of tables (competition classes) is fixed.

```
SELECT table_name, last_update FROM (
  SELECT `Results_Table_1` as table_name, MAX(UPDATE_TIME) 
  last_update FROM Results_Table_1
  UNION
  SELECT `Results_Table_2` as table_name, MAX(UPDATE_TIME) 
  last_update FROM Results_Table_2
  UNION
  SELECT ...
) all_tables
ORDER BY last_update DESC;
```

Comment: This is for a live results program. See the URL below to what it looks like. You can see the comment the order they should be in at the bottom and notice that they are not.

https://whatssmokinliveresults.com/view.php?event=Midwest%20Winter%20Nationals%20-%20Session%201

Comment: From what you have said, and the look of that page, you are storing competition results but putting each "class' in a separate table. Since all the results have the same columns you could store them in the same table and that would make sorting them much easier.

Comment: When I first started this project that never crossed my mind. Once I got deep in to it, that was something I thought about, but really don't want to go through and change everything as I need this by next Wednesday and I'm starting to run out of time. Hoping to just get it working with each "class" being it's own table.

Comment: I've updated my answer to give one solution to your problem using the table structure you have  - but it will only work if the number of tables is fixed and the names are known in advance

Comment: @Tony  Your answer is classic.  Brent should already know the total number of Competition classes and be prepared for his Wednesday deadline.  Good Job.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work by using multidimensional arrays and then merging them. I was able to sort the merged array and then loop through it to display it on the website. Thank you for your input though!

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work by using multidimensional arrays and then merging them. I was able to sort the merged array and then loop through it to display it on the website. Below is the code I added to get it to work. Used a foreach to loop through array and display the tables.

```
$con->select_db($event);
$result = $con->query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$event'");
$classes = array();
$updateTime = array();
            
if(mysqli_num_rows($selectClass) > 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectClass)) {
     $classes[] = $row;
   }
}
            
foreach ($classes as $class) {
   $className = $class['TABLE_NAME'];         
   $result2 = $con->query("SELECT MAX(`Update`) AS 'UPDATE' FROM `$className`");
   while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result5)) {
      $updateTime[] = $row2;
   }
}
            
$new_arr = array_map("array_merge", $classes, $updateTime);
array_multisort(array_column($new_arr, "UPDATE"), SORT_DESC, $new_arr );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Good to hear you have it working. Looks like you have mismatched variable names `$result2` and `$result5` but I imagine that's not in your actual code if it's working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Try to run below and in the output youll get the dynamic SQL for all the tables in union just add order by update_time at last and little bit syntax adjustment of the output sqls

```
With tabs as 
(
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myDatabase' 
)
Select 'Select '|| table_name ||', ' ||
update_time || ' from ' || table_name|| ' union ' from tabs;
```